# Proof of $\Box (A\land B) \leftrightarrow \Box A \land \Box B$ in propositional modal logics

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I'm searching for an example proof of the above formula as distribution over and in basic proportional modal logic, I.e. in some of the standard systems K, S4 or S5.

Comment: See for example the Blackburn, de Rijke, Venama book "Modal logic". There you can find the hard direction as example 1.40 (at least in the version that I have; at any rate it's in chapter one). The other direction is very easy, it's just monotonicity: $p\land q\to p$ is a tautology, so by necessitation $\Box (p\land q\to p)$ which by K yields $\Box (p\land q)\to \Box p$. You can similarly show that $\Box(p\land q)\to\Box q$ and from this you conclude that $\Box(p\land q)\to\Box p\land \Box q$.

Comment: Sadly, I don't have access to this book but I'm trying to get it. Thanks

Comment: I would copy the answer here, but now it's closed. I voted to reopen. Have you found the book?

Comment: Online to buy, yes but I hadn't bought it yet. Would be extremely helpful if you could post it.

Comment: I will write it here in the comments until it's reopened. $$1.\vdash p\to(q\to p\land q)$$ $$2. \vdash\Box(p\to(q\to p\land q))$$ $$3. \vdash\Box p\to \Box(q\to p\land q)$$ $$4. \vdash\Box p\to (\Box q\to \Box(p\land q))$$ $$5.\vdash\Box p\land \Box q\to\Box(p\land q)$$ The first step is a tautology, the second is necessitation, the third is K, the forth is K and the fifth is Currying https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying#Logic (so it's basic propositional logic).